# Is there a way to apply shapiro.test() to a column based on specific category of another column?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a data named df as you can see in the picture. I want to apply shapiro test for the column "value" but based on different color category. Here below you can see my code which is giving the following error "Caused by error:! `shapiro.test(value)` must be a vector, not a  object.". I would appreriate your suggestions.

```
 df %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarise(shapiro.test(value))
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not share images of data. Instead use `dput` to prove a minimal, representative sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users on this site seems to be overusing `tidyverse` solutions when there are simple base R solutions. Here is one, with some simulated data:

```r
df <- data.frame(value=rnorm(200), color=c(rep("blue", 100), rep("red", 100)))

with(df, tapply(value, color, shapiro.test))
$blue

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.98655, p-value = 0.4078


$red

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.98544, p-value = 0.3417
```

`with` and its cousin `within`  are very useful, making for clean code and seems to be underused.

An alternative syntax using the native pipe is

```r
df |> with(tapply(value, color, shapiro.test))
```

resulting in exactly the same output as above.

Comment: This to me seems clearly simpler that the solution by user @akrun

Comment: @akrun:  OK, R has many dialects it seems ... people should at least learn R base well before the tidyverse ...

Answer (score 3):

We can wrap it in a `list` as the output is a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarise(out = list(shapiro.test(value)), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `tibble` with `tidy` and `unnest` the tibble

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    reframe(out = broom::tidy(shapiro.test(value)), .by = 'color') %>%
    unnest(where(is_tibble))
```